# Why does the server say "connection lost, timed out" after joining a minigame?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Okay, I have already got this problem a few times, and it disappeared after a few days but I want to play Minecraft when my friends are online.

The problem is: I start Minecraft and I go to multiplayer to join some servers. But everytime I want to join it takes quite a while before the server loads. Okay, that's no problem. But if you're in the server you want to play minigames or go to survival or creative or something like that. If I then for example want to join my survival, it loads a while (again) and then says 'connection lost;timed out' and it keeps doing that.

I tried restarting my computer, and tried several times to join the server but it just doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you have a bad connection. When you get into the hub/lobby, press tab and see how many bars you have. The more, the better.

Answer (score 2):

I have to second Ethan's answer. Try going to http://www.speedtest.net and comparing your speed to other people's. Then go to http://www.pingtest.net/ and do the same thing.

This will give you an idea of the condition of your network.

The least likely possibility would be that your router or operating system is actively blocking the game. Though people will disagree, I'd suggest turning your firewall off if you are behind a router, as a router provides EXACTLY the same functionality as a firewall network wide.

If you are NOT connected to a router and are instead connected directly to a modem of some sort I would NOT disable your firewall.

If you continue to have issues, try looking up port forwarding for the game.

Hope I have been helpful, and good luck!